# Should user validation of login details be done in a different class than the code behind for the form

Tags: c#, authentication

I am relatively new to C#, and I am trying to build an application which begins with straightforward user authentication prior to launching my main application window.

At the moment, I have a login form asking for domain and user password.
I then use the principalcontext class to authenticate the details.

Here is the code called when the button is clicked on the login form(after name and password are entered)

```
private void validatelogin(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  password = passwordBoxICCLogin.Password.ToString();
  username = tbUserName.Text.ToString();

  using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "xxx"))
  {
    bool  isValid = pc.ValidateCredentials(_username, _password);
    if (isValid)
    {
      DevLauncher launch = new DevLauncher();
      launch.Show();
      this.Close();
    }
    else
    { 
      MessageBox.Show("Invalid ID \ Password combination entered");
    }
  }
}
```

This will probably seem basic to the experienced amongst you, but I would like to implement a sensible, neat design, and figure if I get this right it is a good foundation for the rest of the app.

1) Should all of this user authentication occur in the code behind for the form, or should I create a new class, called say ValidateUser, which handles the user authentication, and call this from the event, with ValidateUser returning a boolean?
I have a nagging feeling that authenticating details should not occur direct on the code behind for the form?

2) Following on from this, I set properties in the code behind form to hold username and password. If I create a validate user  class, should these properties be contained in this class ?

3) Should my NUNIT test for this method simply test the boolean returned from the validatecredentials method. i.e assert.equals(True, validatecredentailsobject(username, domain) - or something along these lines?

Again this doesn't feel quite right. Looking for guidance as to how the overall design could be better, and on writing a method that is testable in NUNIT.

I would like to develop the rest of the app writing the nunit test first, then the method.

Comment: If what's really nagging you is "Is it a good idea to store a username and password that can be trivially found back in the paging file or snooped by a keyboard logger" then you're on to something.  Adding a layer of authentication beyond the tried and tested secure Windows login is a Really Bad Idea.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of prompting for a username and password, you can store a list of usernames (Windows ID's) in your database and then use the following code to get the username of the user logged onto the computer:

```
string userName = Environment.UserName.ToLower();
```

Then compare userName to what is in your database.

You can do this in your Form's constructor before InitializeComponent() like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        string userName = Environment.UserName.ToLower();

        if(isAuthorized(userName)){
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        else {
            MessageBox.Show("You are not authorized");
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
}
```

where isAuthorized is your function to check the users authorization level.

Comment: This answer is just to help give an idea of one way to do the authentication.  I can't help with the nUnit part of your question.  Doing this method though, you don't need to store any usernames/passwords within your application, and you won't need to do any revalidating.  Just check once when they try to run the program and you can assume the privileges won't change once they are in.